# SAS Adaptivereg Limiting Breakpoints

Tags: sas, breakpoints, linear-regression

I am using SAS's adaptivereg procedure to create a piece-wise linear function with temperature (temp) as my x variable and Usage (usage_value) as my y variable. I can use the details of adaptivereg procedure to find the ranges of the different linear functions of the piece-wise function. Is there a way I can limit the number of ranges, (i.e. instead of having 8 linear functions in the piece-wise function, I want to limit it to 5 linear functions). Are there any options I can add that would let me limit the amount of linear functions?

Below is the code I am using. Where a1 is the name of my data set, temp is the independent variable, and usage_value is the dependent variable.

```
proc adaptivereg data=a1 plots=all details=bases;
    model usage_value = temp;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I love adaptivereg. It's such a cool little procedure.

You can use the `df` option in the `model` statement to control the total number of knots to consider, and the `maxbasis` option to control the maximum number of knots in the final model. The higher the degrees of freedom that you use, the fewer the knots.

```
proc adaptivereg data=sashelp.air;
    model air = date / df=12 maxbasis=3;
run;
```

You can also use the `alpha=` option to fine-tune it. Increasing alpha will result in more knots.

An alternative approach can be using the `pbspline`/`spline` options in `transreg` or `proc quantreg`, respectively.

```
proc transreg data=sashelp.air;
    model identity(air) = pbspline(date / evenly=6);
run;

proc quantreg data=sashelp.air;
    effect sp = spline(date / knotmethod=equal(12) );
    model air = sp / quantile=0.5;
run;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a go. I'm outputting the basis details using details = bases.

I'm looking to find the different linear functions and their respective ranges, slopes, and y-intercepts. I am outputting the basis details and I'm wondering how this information maps to the ranges, slopes, and y-intercepts that I'm looking for. I'm basically not sure how to use the information given to predict my y value (usage_value) based on a given x value (temp).